# MySQL Performant Data Aggregation

Tags: mysql, metrics, database-partitioning

I am looking to identify a strategy for performing a scheduled aggregation query using MySQL [Scheduled Events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html) that execute `SELECT ... GROUP BY` statements. For perspective, I have roughly 800k records that need to be moved every 30 minutes. As you can imagine, the `SELECT ... GROUP BY` puts a lock on `INSERT`s for longer than one would like. Also, I've got the table partitioned by hour so that it's fairly easy to lop off the oldest set of data that I wish to keep.

I've been looking at new features like [Exchange Partition](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-management-exchange.html) that would allow me to "copy" a partition to another table without locking potential inserts. However, while that partition is removed, I will obviously have a set of missing data for a short period of time.

What strategies have others employed to aggregate high-fidelity data without locking writes?

Comment: Although it is a development question, I'm pretty sure you could get an even better help on http://dba.stackexchange.com/ You may try there also.